# Open workbooks in current directory

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master workbook which includes a list of files `(E14:E26)`, some of which are blank (empty) cells. I need code to loop through the list and open the workbooks listed (all of which are in the current directory). I've tried this code but get error messages:

```
Sub SkipBlankCells()
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, FName As String

    Set rng = Range("E14:E26")

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            FName = cell.Value
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=FName
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What values are in the cells? Are they complete paths to the files?

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  "File not Found" will require a different solution to "Type Mismatch"

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the cells don't contain the whole path to the workbooks, just the filenames so this should work:

```
    Sub SkipBlankCells()
        Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, FName As String

        Set rng = Range("E14:E26")

        For Each cell In rng
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                FName = vbNullString
                FName = Dir(thisworkbook.Path & "\" & cell.Value) 'use dir to get the filename. If it doesn't exists, it will return blank
                If Not FName = vbNullString then Workbooks.Open _
                   Filename:=Thisworkbook.Path & "\" & FName 'to open a workbook you need the whole path to it, not only the file name.
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of `"\"` and this will even work on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: Just wondering... After checking `If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then`, is there a possible scenario, in which this check would be false - `If Not FName = vbNullString`?

Comment: I'm sorry but how would it Crash @SiddharthRout? I have an If to check the FName, if it's empty it won't crash. @Pᴇʜ thanks! I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

This function should work. I think that the problem of your function was the path. To solve that I used the function `ActiveWorkbook.Path` but just for you to know, you can use a literal path for example `"C:\Users\bor\Documents\folder_with_files"` to use a different path.

```
Sub open_file_list()
    first_row = 14 'in your case
    last_row = 26 'in your case
    For i = first_row To last_row
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5)) Then 'Check for empty
            file = Cells(i, 5)
            Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & file)
            End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks.Open` will fail if a file does not exist.